# IIS rewrite module canonical URL with two domains

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2012

I have a webserver and I have two domains with name `http://example.mx` and `http://example.com.mx` both are pointing to the same webserver and root folder, I can use my website with both domains and for the moment I can use `www.` as well but this is what I want to remove, I did it and I got this web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="CGI-exe" />
            <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="true" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2" enabled="false">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com\.mx$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com.mx/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="false">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.mx$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.mx/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="http a https" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But the problem is the I go to `http://example.mx` it sends me to `http://example.com.mx` and it suppose to works like this:

If I go to `http://www.example.mx` redirects to `http://example.mx`

If I go to `http://www.example.com.mx` redirects to `http://example.com.mx`

but right now if I go to `http://www.example.mx` it redirects to `http://example.com.mx` and I dont want this, What I need to change in the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this rules:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com\.mx$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com.mx/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.mx$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.mx/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```